# it's possible to save materials in cycles node editor to reuse them in other project?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

instead of copy and paste them from other projects I'd like to store them somehow and load them directly

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .blend file that is a master collection of your finished materials, and then *Link* (not Append) this to your various other .blends.

[image: Linking]

Be cautious with this kind of workflow though, because if you change anything in this master file it means your materials in all other .blends may render differently - so for example, re-rendered frames of animation may look different.

It's generally best to work with Linked files on a *project* basis, not a *global* basis.